# Columned Text grabbing in c++

Tags: c++, file, for-loop

I have a file that looks like the following

```
61101
test
3   69.7139 65.3935 22.2632
3   69.7708 65.6131 21.467
2   69.8974 66.0987 20.7391
```

I am trying to have it so that the first two lines are skipped and I average the last three columns as long as the first column is not 4.

this is what I am trying at the moment, but it doesn't really seem to be working.

```
getline(frames_file,tempS);
getline(frames_file,tempS);
while(frames_file.good())
{
    if(typePart != 4)
    {
        frames_file >> typePart >> posPart[0] >> posPart[1] >> posPart[2];
        numLipid++;
        aPos[0] = aPos[0] + posPart[0];
        aPos[1] = aPos[1] + posPart[1];
        aPos[2] = aPos[2] + posPart[2];
    }
}
aPos[0] = aPos[0]/numLipid;
aPos[1] = aPos[1]/numLipid;
aPos[2] = aPos[2]/numLipid;

cout << " " << aPos[0] << " " << aPos[1] << " " << aPos[2];
```

this did not seem to grab any values

Comment: What's the initial value of `typePart`?  What do you mean by "doesn't really seem to be working"?  If `typePart` is actually 4, do you realise you have an infinite loop and will not read anything from the stream?  Do you even enter the loop?  Perhaps your file isn't even open.  How aggressively have you actually tried to debug this issue?

Comment: i have set the intial value to 0. I have i have tried placing a couple of cout to see what outputs are happening, it seems like tempS does not have a value,  and it seems like that is also the case, when the i look at the outputs in the for loop. I am having trouble figuring out how file io exactly works in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple problems here.

```
getline(frames_file,tempS);
getline(frames_file,tempS);
while(frames_file.good())
```

Suppose the file only contained two lines. The expected result here is to just read those two lines, and finish.

Unfortunately, `good()` will still be `true` here, so the rest of the code will go off the rails. `good()`, generally speaking, indicates that the input stream's prior operations succeeded. Well, here the prior operations succeeded. You read the two lines successfully.

`good()` should be checked *after* attempting the next read operation, to determine if it succeeded, or failed.

```
if(typePart != 4)
{
    frames_file >> typePart >> posPart[0] >> posPart[1] >> posPart[2];
```

Can you explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) how you expect `typePart` to be set to 4 *before* you read the next line in question? Based on your question, as I undestood it, you should be reading every line, and only performing calculations when the first column is 4. Here, you mysteriously expect `typePart` to be set to 4 even before you read the line in question.

To summarize:

- Use std::getline() to read every line in your file, not just the first two. This is in order for you to next step correctly:
- **AFTER** each call to `std::getline()`, check either `good()`, or `eof()` to determine if `std::getline()` failed because you reached the end of the file. If so, stop at this point, otherwise:
- Stuff your read line into a `std::istringstream`, and use it to actually extract the pieces of the line using `operator>>`, if that's how you prefer to parse it. Or, use any other approach to parsig that you prefer.
- Check if `typePart` is 4, and then perform all of your calculations *AFTER* you extracted the parts of the line, not before.